# Android Volley - setAdapter in Fragment returns Null Pointer

Tags: android, json, android-volley

**CategoryFragment**:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container,
                false);

        va = new CategoryAdapter();

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.catListView);
        listView.setAdapter(va);

       ...

       JsonArrayRequest jr = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            ...

       return rootView;
       }
```

**CategoryAdapter**:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<CategoryModel> arrCategory;
    private LayoutInflater lf;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrCategory.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return arrCategory.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder vh;

        if (view == null) {
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            view = lf.inflate(R.layout.row_category_listview, null);
            vh.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            vh.tvCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
            view.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        CategoryModel nm = arrCategory.get(i);
        vh.tvTitle.setText(nm.getTitle());
        vh.tvCount.setText(nm.getCount());

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvCount;
    }

}
    }
}
```

I'm using Volley to parse JSON from an API. The main activity of my project here handles a navigation drawer, so I have to use `CategoryFragment` to display a listview of categories.

However, by running the above code, I got this error:

```
01-08 17:43:37.950: E/AndroidRuntime(9897): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 17:43:37.950: E/AndroidRuntime(9897):     at com.package.adapter.VolleyAdapter.getCount(VolleyAdapter.java:21)
01-08 17:43:37.950: E/AndroidRuntime(9897):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:462)
01-08 17:43:37.950: E/AndroidRuntime(9897):     at com.package.fragment.CategoryFragment.onCreateView(CategoryFragment.java:54)
```

Anyone knows why it returns `nullpointerexception` when setting the adapter? I'm not really sure where the problem caused. Is it because it cannot find the fragment layout?

If anything, please let me know.

Comment: your `arrCategory.` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you never initialized `arrCategory`. Create a constructor for your adapter and assign to arrCategory the one you provide in the constructor

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private ArrayList arrCategory;
   public CategoryAdapter(ArrayList dataSet) {
      this.arrCategory = dataSet;
   }
  // other code
}
```

Comment: Got it. Forgot to add that one. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2):

`private ArrayList<CategoryModel> arrCategory;`

is never initialized.

You need to pass the arraylist from your fragment to the constructor of adapter class. First you need to make sure it is populated.

So get the data using volley. Populate the list.

then

```
 new  CategoryAdapter(list);
 //this should be after getting data from volley
```

Then

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private ArrayList<type> arrCategory;
   public CategoryAdapter(ArrayList<type> dataSet) {
      this.arrCategory = dataSet;
   }
```

Comment: @Ketan why should it be.?

Comment: this is the failure, so its legitim to post it as answer

Comment: @Raghunandan sorry..I removed.

Answer (score 1):

arrCategory is null you should initialize it:

```
private ArrayList<CategoryModel> arrCategory = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>();
```